# JQuery loader doesn't work on JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery loading screen that is shown when a form submit button is pressed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $("#plotLoader").show();
    });
});
```

The form is mainly `select` types but I also have a JQuery Datepicker to select a date. The loading screen shows perfectly for the `select` types but it doesn't show at all when I choose a date from the Datepicker?

What could be causing this and is there a way to fix it?

**EDIT:**

Here is some more of my code as requested.

HTML form:

```
<form id="options" method="post" action="SQLselecter.jsp">

        Plot Type: 
        <select name="PlotType" id="PlotType">
            <option value="Point">Point</option>
            <option value="Line">Line</option>
            <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
            <option value="Pie">Pie</option>
        </select>

        ADACS:
        <select name="ADACS" id="ADACS">
            <option value="ADACS">ADACS</option>
            <option value="ADACS">ADACS</option>
            <option value="ADACS">ADACS</option>
            <option value="ADACS">ADACS</option>
        </select>

        Skyline: 
        <select name="Skyline" id="Skyline">
            <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
            <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
            <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
            <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
        </select>

        AccessType:
        <select name="AccessType" id="AccessType">
            <option value="AccessType">AccessType</option>
            <option value="AccessType">AccessType</option>
            <option value="AccessType">AccessType</option>
            <option value="AccessType">AccessType</option>
        </select>

        Dates:
        <input type="text"  id="datepickerFrom" name="fromDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
        <input type="text"  id="datepickerTo" name="toDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">

        <div id="buttons">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Plot Graph" onclick="return check();">
        </div>
</form>
```

Javacript

```
function check()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('PlotType').value=="") {
        alert ("Please select plot type.");
        return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('datepickerFrom').value=="" && document.getElementById('datepickerTo').value==""
                && document.getElementById('Skyline').value=="" && document.getElementById('ADACS').value=="" && document.getElementById('AccessType').value=="" ) {
            alert ("Please select at least one search parameter.");
            return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('datepickerFrom').value!="" || document.getElementById('datepickerTo').value!="") {

            if (document.getElementById('datepickerFrom').value==""
             || document.getElementById('datepickerFrom').value==null )
            {
                alert ("Please Enter 'From date'.");
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('datepickerTo').value==""
                || document.getElementById('datepickerTo').value==null)
               {
                   alert ("Please Enter 'To date'.");
                   return false;
               }
            return true;
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                $("#plotLoader").show();
            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: You mentioned in a comment on the current answer that there's additional code; can you edit that into the question? Some idea of the HTML structure would be good, too. Even better would be a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem, provided you also include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I have updated my code as requested. Sorry I can not do a jsFiddle as it is blocked where I work.

Comment: found the problem! I had `return true;` in the datepicker check statement. I removed this and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#plotLoader").show();
});
```

**UPDATE:**

**The Work Around**

you must create two buttons:

1. the real submit button given the CSS `visibility:hidden;`
2. a dummy button ( a figure button or a div that looks like a button which actually does nothing other than showing the loader and triggering the real submit button!)

**The Explanation**

use the dummy button in the same place where you want the real button to be (I mean position it in the same place)

on click event of the dummy button write:

```
$('#dummy').click(function(){
    $("#plotLoader").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#submit').trigger('click');
    },500);
});
```

now the users can see the loader while the browser is actually processing the redirection.

Comment: When I add `e.preventDefault();` the select options how the loader but then the page is not redirected (I guess preventDefault stops this?). But oddly if I select a date from the datepicker the loading screen still doesn't show but the page IS redirected..

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` stops the page from redirecting, you are correct. but if you don't use it, the page will be redirected immediately, so there's no need to use a loader as it will not be seen.

Comment: I am plotting graphs (using R) and big data can take a lot of time so the loader is there as feedback so the user knows something is happening and doesn't refresh the page before it has plotted.

Comment: still the page tries to be redirected immediately, so the user can't see anything as no jQuery codes are being processed then. I've come up with a workaround, check my update in a few minutes

Comment: @AminJafari "still the page tries to be redirected immediately, so the user can't see anything as no jQuery codes are being processed then." That's not true.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist care to say why? I meant when the form is submitting, the page will not respond to jQuery, that's what I've always experienced.

Comment: I've tried the update and I'm still getting the same results. Maybe I have something else that is interfering e.g the Submit button does a form check in JS but I didn't think that would make a difference because it only checks the input aren't empty.

Comment: try to set the `$('#submit').trigger('click')` inside a `setTimeout`, check the last part of the update again to see how

Comment: With the code I have in my question, when the Submit button is pressed the user **does** see the JQuery loader when a `select` option is selected but **does not** see the loader when a datepicker date is selected... hope that make sense.

Comment: @AminJafari If the page reloads quickly after the form submits it can *appear* as though any subsequent jQuery code didn't execute, even though it did. If all JavaScript execution stopped the moment a form was submitted it would be impossible to bind event handlers for the 'submit' event, or others that are fired after the initial form submission.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist then what is the problem here?

Comment: @AminJafari If I knew that I would have posted an answer already; there's not enough information in the question to say.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thanks for the correction anyways, I'll try double-checking it later.